# Rails: Routing error when using ajax with a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to rails and have followed the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899037/rails-ajax-fav-button-for-user-posts).

This is how things are in my project:

Controller:

```
def create
  def create
      current_user.likes.create(:post_id => params[:post_id])
      render :layout => false
   end
end
```

.js file:

```
$ ->
    $(".like").click ->
        post_id = $(this).attr('id')
        $.ajax
            type: 'POST'
            url: 'likes/' + post_id
            success: ->
                alert "succsess!"
```

Routes.rb

```
Sample::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :likes

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :posts, only: [:create, :destroy]

  root              to: 'pages#home'
  match '/about',   to: 'pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact'
  match '/help',    to: 'pages#help'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  post  '/likes/4', to: 'likes#create', :as => :like
end
```

(I use '/likes/4' for testing proposes (it will be 'post_id' in the future)).

When I click on the Like button in the view, the like get stored in the db, but  I get this error(when I look at the console with inspector in Chrome)...

```
POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/likes/4 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

...and I never get the succsess alert from the ajax.

When I run `wget --post-data='' http://localhost:3000/likes/4`, I get:

```
--2012-07-22 19:35:01--  http://localhost:3000/likes/4
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1, fe80::1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:3000... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2012-07-22 19:35:02 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Anyone know what makes this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem!

First, thanks to Dougui for making some good points that helped me on the way!

Solution:

I had to change the uniqueness validation from:

```
validates :tag, :uniqueness => {:scope => :post}
```

to:

```
validates :tag_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :post_id}
```

You probably wonder why? It is explained here: http://thetenelements.blogspot.no/2011/08/undefined-method-text-for-nilnilclass.html

So here is my files when things are working:

**like.rb**

```
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :post_id}
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
```

**likes_controller.rb**

```
def userLikePost
   current_user.likes.create(:post_id => params[:post_id])
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/likes/:post_id', to: 'likes#userLikePost'
```

**pages.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
    $(".like.btn.btn-mini").click (e) ->
        if $(this).attr("class") == "like btn btn-mini"
            post_id = $(this).attr('id')
            $.post '/likes/' + post_id
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).addClass("active")
```

**html button**

```
<button class="like btn btn-mini" id="<%= feed_item.id %>"><i class="icon-heart"></i></button>
```

And in the user and post model I have `has_many: likes`

Hope this can help others :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you do a post and your route is a get. You can show it when you tape the command `rake routes`. Try to change your ajax request type to GET or change your routes. Replace `match` by `post`.

Comment: Thanks Dougui! It works when I replace 'GET' with 'POST' in the .js file, but I need to send some information with the ajax request (then I need to use POST, right?). But it does not work when I replace 'match' with 'post' in routes.rb. Any sugestions?

Comment: I meant replace 'POST' with 'GET' in the .js file :)

Comment: I think you can send some information with GET too. Can you send the result of your `rake routes` command please.

Comment: This is when I use 'GET' in the .js file and 'match' in routes.rb file. Is this what you need? (Sorry for all the comments, but it was hard to make it look readable otherwise).

Comment: `likes_4 /likes/4(.:format) likes#create` is not normal. Can you send your routes.rb (edit your first post). I understand for all the comments.

Comment: Edited it now. I have changed the .js file to use 'POST', and 'post' instead of 'match' in routes.rb. This way the like gets stored in the db, but I still get the error and never get the succsess alert from the ajax.

Comment: try to tape the command `wget --post-data='' http://localhost:3000/likes/4` just to see if routes work without ajax

Comment: hmmm, then I get `-bash: wget: command not found`. (Im working on OSX 1.7).

Comment: I don't know what's the command for macosx. It's a command to do a http request. Useful to test.

Comment: I found and installed the wget (It seems like it does not bundle with Xcode anymore). Posted the result in the question.