# User authors many articles, also has a list of favorite articles Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database of users which is related by a has_many relationship to a articles database.

I would like a user to be able to have a list of favorite articles, for which he is not the author.  I'm not sure how to implement this.  I initially thought of an array for the user which holds all the id's of the posts which he favorited, but there seems like a more intuitive way to do it.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899037/rails-ajax-fav-button-for-user-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'd like the favorites to live in the database as well as the author relationship.  The way to do this is to add another join table, perhaps called "favorite_articles".

```
create_table :favorite_articles, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :article_id
end

# also add foreign keys, assuming you're using a database that supports them
```

Then add a model for it which :belongs to both users and articles and use the [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association in both users and articles.  You will have to name the association something other than articles, though.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorite_articles
  has_many :favorites, :through => :favorite_articles, :class_name => "Article"
end

class FavoriteArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorite_articles
  has_many :users_who_favorited, :through => :favorite_articles, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Comment: This is smart way to do it.